# how to truncate/add-ellipsis the overflown text in echarts in axis label

Tags: echarts

How to truncate the long name in the axis, in the below image see the long text `World4 is not enough and check this one is truncating or not` is overflowing the chart.

[image]

How can we automatically apply the ellipsis for this kind of long name in e-charts.

In echarts I know that the ellipsis can be applied by setting maxWidth, I need to apply the ellipsis automatically when the text is long enough over the container

The expected result can be as in the screenshot below. (I added three dots in the image editor after the long text)

[image]

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/echart-demo-histogram-manage-with-options-60uojy